# SAR: Why can images have complex pixels?

Tags: radar

I come from an astronomical long-baseline interferometry background, where images are synthesized from sampled complex visibilities (Fourier components). LBI and polarization can be combined when complex visibilities are measured with a polarimeter or horns. All sources are assumed spatially incoherent on the "celestial sphere," which is really far away. I understand all of the relevant LBI definitions and mathematics.

I've recently started dealing with SAR imagery. I thought that all of the definitions and mathematics I learned from LBI would be useful for SAR, and for the most part they are. I find myself, however, being confused by one particular piece of SAR terminology. Google searches have served only to confuse me more.

I've been looking at "H polarization" SAR images. The pixels are complex numbers (real/imaginary or amplitude/phase), which is weird to me because all LBI images have real pixels. I believe that the "phase" comes from the difference of the outgoing LFM phase and the return LFM phase within the pulses (like the fringe phase with respect to the envelope peak of LBI fringe packets).

For LBI, a Stokes I image would be HH* + VV*, which has real pixels. If the same were true for SAR images, the pixels would also be real. What am I missing? Are "H polarization" images complex because coherent returns of a scene (as opposed to incoherent for LBI) yield complex numbers because of the way they are synthesized? Or, are the "H polarization" images proportional to complex electric fields instead of squared magnitude of electric fields?

EDIT: I have recently seen mention that HH* may have a different meaning from what I'm used to, namely send out H and receive H.  In LBI, HH* means square (and average) H field.  I'm not sure if this has any bearing on this.

Comment: your question may be a better fit at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where do the pixels come from in a SAR image?  Are you referring to resolution (along track and cross track)?  Or are you talking about the sampled RF (IF) of a SAR return?

Comment: @jsotola  I will try that, thanks.

Comment: @SteveSh I'm actually speaking about the final data product, a SAR image of a scene.

Comment: " I have recently seen mention that HH* may have a different meaning from what I'm used to, namely send out H and receive H".  While I'm not familiar with that notation, I do know that SAR systems sometimes like to receive on the opposite polarization than what is transmitted, because of the way different objects/materials (natural foliage vs man made stuff) interact with the RF.

Comment: Obs data in LBI are also complex, as you obtain the phase information in every detector and every "pixel". Otherwise, you couldn't induce the interference information. So could you clarify what you mean with LBI having real valued pixels?

Comment: @tobalt LBI measurements are correlated complex electric fields, which are Fourier components (visibilities) of image intensities. The image intensities are real because of symmetries in the complex visibilities.  Note that the original electric fields on the "celestial sphere" are completely uncorrelated.  They become correlated as they propagate toward the observer.  The SAR images that I'm looking at, however, are complex, not real. I'm not sure what I'm looking at.  If they are image intensities, why are they complex?  Are they just proportional to (coherent) electric fields?

Comment: Let's try this.  The SAR pixels are complex because the radar (the R is SAR) return is sampled/processed in a quadrature fashion.  The LO used in down converting the RF return has an in-phase and a 90 deg out of phase signal.  It is these quadrature samples that allow you to obtain phase information, and so makes the sampled data complex.  It has nothing to do with the polarization of the transmitted or received signal.

Comment: HH* is some kind of matrix decomposition for orthogonality, you would have to know the signal model to know what they meant

Comment: @SteveSh Good.  I already knew this, so I'm on the right track.

Comment: I included polarization in my original question when I realized that I didn't understand something, but it may be muddying the waters.  Let's try this ...  In any standard (non SAR) imaging system, we image a spatially incoherent source in the far field.  The detector pixels measure the squared magnitude of the electric field (proportional to intensity).  What about SAR imaging of a coherent source in the far field?  Since the measured image is complex, is the value for each pixel proportional to the electric field (not squared magnitude)?  It makes sense, but I haven't been able to verify it.

Comment: @SteveSh Let me bring back polarization.  I know a lot about that math.  That may help me answer my question.  I have complex Capella SAR images.  How do I calculate the Stokes parameters, in particular Stokes I?  I = \sqrt{|A_H|^2 + |A_V|^2} or I = |A_H|^2 + |A_V|^2? A_H is the H complex pixel value and A_V is the V pixel value.  I think it's the second one, but I'm not sure.  If it's the second, that means that the units of A_H and A_V are proportional to electric fields.

Comment: @tobalt Let me bring back polarization.  I know a lot about that math.  That may help me answer my question.  I have complex Capella SAR images.  How do I calculate the Stokes parameters, in particular Stokes I?  I = \sqrt{|A_H|^2 + |A_V|^2} or I = |A_H|^2 + |A_V|^2? A_H is the H complex pixel value and A_V is the V pixel value.  I think it's the second one, but I'm not sure.  If it's the second, that means that the units of A_H and A_V are proportional to electric fields.

Comment: IMO, you always have to measure the field itself and not the intensity. Only the field information includes phase and let's you combine the data from the individual detectors. That is why LBI doesn't work for optical wavelength, for which you can't achieve phase resolution with electronic detectors, but only measure intensity.

Comment: @tobalt I already know this stuff.  The cross-over point for active phase tracking is about 10 microns.  I don't seem to speak the SAR language.  I just need to know for SAR data if the complex pixels are proportional to the electric fields.